# How to send a message securely via html and php (post)

Tags: php, post, message

I use a php code on my server to send messages to my clients. The programming tool I use (Game Maker) allows me to send messages via php by executing a shell so that the link appears in a browser.

Example is [here](http://www.mysite.com/send.php) ...

with all the other stuff added. So in effect, the message I'm sending and all the stuff I'm sending are seen in the browser. I use the php get method. everything works perfectly now, except that it may not be secured. Someone suggested php post method, but when I replaced get in my php cod on my server to post, and pasted the same thing in the browser, my code didn't work. It's hard to explain, but here's the php code on my server:

```
<?php
// Some checks on $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REFERRER'] and similar headers
// might be in order

// The input form has an hidden field called email. Most spambot will
// fall for the trap and try filling it. And if ever their lord and master checks the bot logs,
// why not make him think we're morons that misspelled 'smtp'?
if (!isset($_GET['email']))
    die("Missing recipient address");
if ('' != $_GET['email'])
{
    // A bot, are you?
    sleep(2);
    die('DNS error: cannot resolve smpt.gmail.com');
    // Yes, this IS security through obscurity, but it's only an added layer which   comes almost for free.
}

$newline = $_GET['message'];

$newline = str_replace("[N]","\n","$newline");
$newline = str_replace("[n]","\n","$newline");

// Add some last-ditch info
$newline .= <<<DIAGNOSTIC_INFO

---
Mail sent from $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]:$_SERVER[REMOTE_PORT]


DIAGNOSTIC_INFO;

mail('info@site.com','missing Password Report',$newline,"From: ".$_GET['from']);

header( 'Location: http://site.com/report.html' ) ;
?>
```

I then call this php code on my site. so that in the end, the whole thing ends up in the browser address bar. I hope this makes sense. How do I make things more secured by using post so that at least the sent information cannot be seen in users history and all that.

Comment: Please note there is nothing secure when switching from GET to POST. WIth POST you simply hide it a little better (if using hidden fields). But everybody can still easily find it. If you need secure communication, switch to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace to POST in your form you need to replace the request to POST too:

```
<?php
// Some checks on $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REFERRER'] and similar headers
// might be in order

// The input form has an hidden field called email. Most spambot will
// fall for the trap and try filling it. And if ever their lord and master checks the          bot logs,
   // why not make him think we're morons that misspelled 'smtp'?
   if (!isset($_POST['email']))
    die("Missing recipient address");
 if ('' != $_POST['email'])
 {  // A bot, are you?
       sleep(2);
     die('DNS error: cannot resolve smpt.gmail.com');
      // Yes, this IS security through obscurity, but it's only an added layer which   comes almost for free.
   }



 $newline = $_POST['message'];

$newline = str_replace("[N]","\n","$newline");
$newline = str_replace("[n]","\n","$newline");

// Add some last-ditch info
  $newline .= <<<DIAGNOSTIC_INFO

---
Mail sent from $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]:$_SERVER[REMOTE_PORT]


DIAGNOSTIC_INFO;

mail('info@site.com','missing Password Report',$newline,"From: ".$_POST['from']);

header( 'Location: http://site.com/report.html' ) ;
?>
```

Unless you are sending it with real GET parameters like `http://www.mysite.com/send.php?email=etc`; in this case you do need to set it to GET to retrieve the variables.

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem. 

  http://www.mysite.com/send.php?email=etc...

This is how I send my message

Comment: do you mean change the METHOD on the form to "post"

Comment: @YawAnsong Send the mails with a form that is set to POST. Don't enter the url directly.